# Re-define wait method in a Java interface

Tags: java, sql, object, overloading, api-design

I would like to use `wait(int)` as the signature of a method in a fluent API (used for http://www.jooq.org). The goal is to be able to construct SQL queries like this example:

```sql
SELECT * FROM T_AUTHOR
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
FOR UPDATE OF FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
WAIT 5
```

The full `FOR UPDATE` clause syntax specification (at least for Oracle) can be seen here:

```sql
FOR UPDATE [ OF [ [ schema. ] { table | view } . ] column
             [, [ [ schema. ] { table | view } . ] column]...]
[ { NOWAIT | WAIT integer | SKIP LOCKED } ]
```

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/img_text/for_update_clause.htm

With jOOQ, I really want to stay close to the SQL syntax. So I'd like to be able to model the above SQL clause with the jOOQ fluent API like this:

```java
Result<Record> result = create.select()
                              .from(T_AUTHOR)
                              .limit(1)
                              .forUpdate()
                              .of(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME)
                              .wait(5) // Here's the issue
                              .fetch();
```

The fetch method is used to render the API's underlying object as SQL and run the SQL statement against an Oracle (or any other) database. The above can be legally specified in an interface:

```java
/**
 * A type that models a "step" in the creation of a query using the fluent API
 */
public interface SelectForUpdateWaitStep extends SelectFinalStep {
    // [...]

    /**
     * Add a "FOR UPDATE .. WAIT n" clause to the query
     */
    SelectFinalStep wait(int seconds);

    // [...]
}
```

I have some doubts about this, though, because there is a risk of collision with another method:

```java
public class Object {
    // [...]

    public final native void wait(long timeout) throws InterruptedException;

    // [...]
}
```

Thanks to method-overloading (`int` vs. `long` arguments), I can actually do this. But I'm afraid it might confuse my users and lead to mistakes. So this would be wrong:

```java
                              .forUpdate()
                              .of(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME)
                              .wait((long) 5) // This doesn't make sense
                              .fetch();       // This doesn't compile
```

So my questions are:

1. Can I somehow prevent calling/accessing `Object.wait(long)` altoghether? I don't think so because it's declared `final` but maybe someone knows a compiler-trick, or something else?
2. Do you have a better idea for my API design apart from just renaming the method to something silly like `doWait(int)` or `WAIT(int)`?

Comment: Rename to `pause()` instead. Non-silly, clear and no compiler trickery risks.

Comment: @Pontus, haha. :) OK but the `SQL` statement clause is really `WAIT`. No one will ever guess why it's named `pause()`: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/img_text/for_update_clause.htm

Comment: Don't you just hate the enforced `Object` inheritance crap?

Comment: Another option is to make your `wait` take two arguments: a number and a unit of time (makes sense, doesn't look silly, has a distinct signature)

Comment: @DeadMG, yeah, it especially spoils auto-completion in any IDE. You always have at least those 9 useless methods, that hardly anyone ever uses, apart from `equals()` and maybe `getClass()`...

Comment: @truthealty: Nice thought. I might sell that as a "feature", even if the rendered SQL only knows a number in seconds. But then again, that's less convenient for users, since they probably want seconds anyway...

Comment: @Lukas: If you don't want to make use of renaming, I would prefer the overloading-with-int option. Since a wrong usage of the wait(xxx) method causes just a compile time error, doing so is reasonable. Moreover, you train the users of your library to read the documentation, what is a good thing ;)

Comment: @Stefan, I think I'm opting for that too. After all, the clause is called `WAIT`, and it does work. I've had enough trouble with the `CASE` and `ELSE` clauses already... ;-)

Comment: Is it guaranteed that return value of `wait(int)` must be used that a statement makes sense? (i.e. calling `fetch()` on it) In other words: Does your API guarantee that using `wait(long)` instead of `wait(int)` results in an compile time error or the statement was non-sense anyway?! When this is guaranteed then I like the `wait(int)` very much ...

Comment: @Fatal: Yes. When you use `void wait(long)`, you will not be able to further use the query, because of the `void` return type. The query is immediately discarded by the garbage collector. On the other hand, you'll probably get compilation errors, because you think you actually used `wait(int)` and you can invoke `fetch()`, `execute()` (or other jOOQ methods accessible from `SelectFinalStep`) on it, which you can't. So there is no chance of runtime errors, just a bit of an awkward and confusing API, maybe. But in any case, the `WAIT` clause is used very very rarely, so I could live with that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this requires is a way to disable an `Object` method. And main reason seems to be because it has a *nice* name that would fit the purposes of a proprietary API.

At first, this contradicts the entire idea of inheritance -- once you inherit from a class, all subclasses must expose the same non-private fields & method. You can always override a method, except when (1) it is marked as `final` and (2) it has an incompatible (non-covariant) return type, both of which are true with the `void wait(long)` method.

Furthermore, since every object is an `Object` in Java, everything must have a method `void wait(long)` and there should be no way to hide/delete/disable/forward/override it. Assuming it were possible to hide the `void wait(long)` method, how would you go about invoking it, should you wish to invoke it?

However, assuming you would never need to invoke `void wait(long)` for your particular classes, there is always the approach of source/byte-code weaving that **AspectJ** uses in order to make changes to the .class Java bytecode based on certain invocation rules. You could trap every call to `wait(long)` and declare an error/warning. See more here: http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/annotations-decp.html

**However**, native method pointcuts are not possible even with AspectJ with byte-code weaving. Most likely, this is not possible even with source-code weaving -- but it might be worth a try.

Comment: That's a nice idea. I hadn't thought of AspectJ. But since this is for a library used by others (http://www.jooq.org), I think I cannot impose aspects like this to my code without requiring my users to also use AspectJ in their projects?

Comment: That is good news -- AspectJ is not the way to do Java development anyway :)

Comment: Yes, it's like rewriting the compiler... ;-)

Comment: I am not quite sure for myself if I like the idea or I should hate it. But it is definitely very interesting.

Comment: @Fatal+Nick: If I had the possibility to rewrite the compiler, then I'd natively add SQL support in Java, kind of like SQL being natively part of PL/SQL or Linq of C#...

Comment: We need more people to think big like you, Lukas!

Comment: You'll get a bounty for the idea with AspectJ here, too. I've to wait 24h until I can reward you with the bounty just set up.

Comment: How considerate of you, still it is exclusively your choice -- 10x, anyway :)

Comment: Thanks Fatal, it's a shame there's no perfect answer for this - except for rewriting the compiler!  Personally I'd happily give up backwards compatibility for a new Java with many of historical mistakes fixed (with so many languages running on the JVM and the ability to cross communicate, backwards compatibility would only be affect source code)

Comment: I set this as the accepted answer. With AspectJ, I could actually "misuse" Java for exactly the purposes I needed, even if I'm not going to do it. But it's a very nice idea

Answer (score 4):

You might try using a `waitFor` method instead, which specifies both a time and a "condition" to wait for. The implementation detail would be hidden, but one possible implementation would be to try your action immediately and loop until the specified condition has been met, with an appropriate pause between attempts.

Here's a sample interface for a `Condition` I use myself (as you can see, it doesn't need to be complex):

```
public interface Condition {
    public boolean met();
}
```

Comment: @Ben, `waitFor(int)` might be the least silly among workarounds :-) I don't need to worry about the implementation, because the implementation is done in Oracle (or any other RDBMS). I just have to render a `WAIT` clause in the generated SQL statement.

Comment: @Ben, I'm not sure if you understood my question. I don't actually do the waiting. The fact that `Object.wait()` collides with my interests is purely because of method-naming. My API should render SQL and execute it in a database... `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE [OF ..] WAIT n` is a clause in a SQL `SELECT` statement

Comment: @Lukas Eder: I did miss that detail. In this particular case then, I'd specify (in the function name) exactly _what_ you're waiting for. E.g., `waitForUpdate(int)` or `waitForSelect(int)`.

Comment: @Ben, the formal definition of the clause (at least for Oracle) can be seen here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/img_text/for_update_clause.htm. It should really "feel" like SQL, so it should really be something like `forUpdate().of(...).wait(...)`, or `forUpdate().noWait()`, or `forUpdate().skipLocked()`, etc...

Comment: @Lukas: I get what you're saying about it having a "feel" like SQL, but I'd avoid using the wait() method, even overloaded (for example with `int` instead of with `long`), because if the user provides the wrong parameters, I suspect it might lead her/him down a confusing path.

Answer (score 3):

`void wait(long)` is a part of the contract offered by `Object` and therefore it should not be changed. Imagine that someone stores your object and attempts to use it for `wait/notify` threading logic. So completely changing it's logic is just playing against the rules. So you will have to come up with different name.

On the other hand, it seems that having `forUpdate` take parameter indicating wait time will fit the bill. You could just have another version of `forUpdate` in addition to existing one.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I'm very sure no one will use `wait/notify` on an intermediate step of SQL construction in my fluent API. That would be just about as weird as to `synchronize` on that object. I had also thought about adding `forUpdateWait(int)`, which isn't a bad idea. The problem is that there is also an optional `of` method, that should come before the `wait()`. So I'm back with the original problem of creating non-SQL, which is hard to understand by my users :-/ I really think that overloading is the least of evil (luckily I use `int`, not `long`)

Comment: @Lukas I actually suggested `forUpdate(long val)` in addition to existing one. I don't see a reason to name it differently. Then you can keep original version, of the method, too and take wait value from any relevant method.  As to whether anyone will use wait/notify on the object - I would not bet on it since it's not under your control and users are known to do weird things. Anyway, the point is that it's against the rules of the game :)

Comment: @Axel, it's not against the rules (but maybe a bit confusing) to declare a method `X wait(int)`, because due to overloading that one is distinct from the one in `Object`. My parameter is `int`, not `long`. My concern was that I might confuse my users. Considering the Oracle SQL definition for the `FOR UPDATE` clause, there really shoudn't be a `forUpdate(int)` method, without the `WAIT` keyword. I'll update my question with the formal SQL syntax definition, as this seems to be a bit confusing, too :-)

Comment: I can see your point. But introducing wait(int) will basically break construction like `wait(5000)` called on your object (I know that you think that it's unlikely). I still don't see why you don't want to just use `forUpdate(5)` especially if wait is always required.

Comment: On that very unlikely event, my users can still call `wait(5000L)` to invoke the `java.lang.Object` method. I really don't want to inverse `WAIT` and `OF` clauses, if not necessary... But it's clearly a viable solution

Comment: +1 for a definitive viable solution. But I think it breaks the SQL-Feeling too much. But I am not that sure since `limit(...)` signature in jooq has a similar issue with the `OFFSET` which is just a parameter of `limit(...)`. So why not having `wait` as parameter of `forUpdate(..)` then? Hmm...

Comment: @Fatal: You can write any of these: `.limit(int)` (most RDBMS), `.limit(int, int)` (MySQL-lingo), `.limit(int).offset(int)` (Postgres-lingo, and many others). For other dialects, `.limit(int).offset(int)` will be simulated using `TOP`, `FETCH FIRST`, etc constructs, which I'm not supporting in the DSL directly, as I think `LIMIT..OFFSET` is the best syntax for this

Answer (score 2):

Hacking around with core Java for the sake of DSL is simply not a good idea.

Why not make your DSL more expressive?

What does wait(int n) mean anyway?  wait for N milliseconds, seconds, minutes?

A better signature would be:

wait(long duration, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit){ ... }

which reads better, for example:

wait(30, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)

Comment: I think the OP is quite keen on the "wait" name, and it is a nice name indeed. Unfortunately, it is already taken by Java.

Comment: I agree that's the way to do it java-like.
The real problem here is to have something that feels like SQL and has not such sideffects like wait(int). Lukas Eder wants it for jooq. I find this project very interesting and one of the key features seem to be this "SQL-Feeling" when writing your queries with this library.

Well, but having error-prone signature (like with wait(int)) is not good either for a serious library. So you're back in race (in my opinion). Pros: good method signature Cons: It's not really feeling like SQL...

Comment: I think anyone suggesting various hacks to override the wait method should be downvoted - the usecase simply doesn't justify such an intrusion.  However I fully understand wanting this to be as SQL-like as possible.

Comment: I am with you having a bad feeling doing things like that. But downvoting is not fair since the question is really about going around this here. It seems so that there is no "THE solution". In my opinion every idea and statement is very welcome. At the end we'll have to look where are the greatest pros and the less cons - and that still depends on personal preferences.

Comment: I've never downvoted anyone and won't start now =)   Just wanted to underline the fact these kind of "solutions" would be a grievous hack (byte code manipulation is the remit of cross-cutting-concerns and middleware) and would ultimately cause somebody pain.  It's definitely just my opinion, but one I feel very strongly about.  (An interesting discussion none the less)

Comment: Guys, no need to downvote :) I'm not interested in hacks. `wait(int)` is going to be a valid solution. `waitFor(int)` was the best workaround so far. But I prefer `wait`. As I stated in previous comments, there's no need to specify the time unit, as that is well-defined in Oracle already. Besides, there is also `Object.wait(long, int)` so the original concern still remains (even if overloading would be a bit less "risky") BTW: Thanks @Fatal, for the bounty. That sure added some interest to the discussion!

Comment: After some days thinking about it:
I came to the conclusion that having `wait(int)` and `wait(long, TimeUnit)` would be best. The downsides of `wait(int)` are acceptable for having a very neat signature. I personally like to have `wait(long, TimeUnit)` too, because it is code convention here to use TimeUnit when converting time things and it perfectly fits the way TimeUnit is used in JDK. Also it is very common to hold time values as `long`. 

Speaking for my projects I would have more trouble with the `wait(int)` thing, because it collidates with other best practices we've established here.

Comment: Got the bounty for method signature `wait(long, TimeUnit)` which is best here in my opinion. Even when it is not _necessary_ to provide the TimeUnit, because it is well-defined by Oracle, it is still viable. Also we can go on using longs in our time-constants without running into the `wait(long)` problem over and over again. Conflicts with `Object.wait(long, int)` are much less dangerous since second type is totally incompatible to `wait(long, TimeUnit)`.

Comment: @Fatal: But I think it's equally confusing. Even more so, because it re-uses the `wait(long...)` signature. I guess there's no perfect solution to this anyway.